# Selenium - Python - Getting timeout exception message for getting the header value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests, pytest

I'm trying to write a Pytest code, and while running the tests, I'm getting TimeOut exception for all them. Below is an excerpt from the logs:

```html
======================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================
_____________________________________________________ Test_Home.test_check_home_page_header[chrome] ______________________________________________________

self = <Tests.test_HomePage.Test_Home object at 0x000001D3DA012430>

    def test_check_home_page_header(self):
        self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
>       homepage = self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)

test_HomePage.py:16:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\Pages\LoginPage.py:29: in do_login
    self.do_send_keys(self.UNAME, username)
..\Pages\BasePage.py:19: in do_send_keys
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="9655edde5d2014440e4ba9fea0b11d55")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located object at 0x000001D3DA038640>, message = ''

    def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

..\localsystem\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80: TimeoutException
______________________________________________________ Test_Home.test_check_home_page_header[edge] _______________________________________________________

self = <Tests.test_HomePage.Test_Home object at 0x000001D3DA0A7D90>

    def test_check_home_page_header(self):
        self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
>       homepage = self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)

test_HomePage.py:16:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\Pages\LoginPage.py:29: in do_login
    self.do_send_keys(self.UNAME, username)
..\Pages\BasePage.py:19: in do_send_keys
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="a940b700b12b4aa923d01faaa45913cc")>
method = <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located object at 0x000001D3DA0A7DC0>, message = ''

    def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

> I have defined the header value in a config class and reading from there.
> I am trying to implement POM, so after the login page is executed, it directly shifts to HomePage. Below is the implementation of code (BaseClass.py):

Timeout definition:

```html
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class BasePage():

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def is_visible(self, by_locator):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
        return bool(element)
```

> Login Page(LoginPage.py)

```
import time
from Pages.BasePage import BasePage
from Pages.HomePage import HomePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from Config.config import TestData

class LoginPage(BasePage):

   UNAME = (By.ID, "UserName")
   PWD = (By.ID, "User_Password")
   LOGIN_BTN = (By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')
   EULA_BTN = (By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='I Agree']")
   
   def __init__(self, driver):
      super().__init__(driver)
      self.driver.get(TestData.BASE_URL)

"""BELOW ARE PAGE ACTIONS FOR LOGIN PAGE"""

   def get_login_page_title(self, title):
      return self.get_title(title)

"""For logging in into the account"""
   def do_login(self, username, password):
      self.do_send_keys(self.UNAME, username)
      self.do_send_keys(self.PWD, password)
      self.do_click(self.LOGIN_BTN)
      self.do_click(self.EULA_BTN)

      return HomePage(self.driver)
```

> Login Page test file (test_LoginPage.py)

```
import pytest
from Config.config import TestData
from Tests.test_Base import BaseTest
from Pages.LoginPage import LoginPagecode

class Test_Login(BaseTest):
    
  def test_login_page_title(self):
      self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
      title = self.loginPage.get_title(TestData.LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE)
      assert title == TestData.LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE

  def test_login(self):
      self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
      self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)
```

> Home Page object definition (HomePage.py)

```html
import time
from Pages.BasePage import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from Config.config import TestData

class HomePage(BasePage):

    HEADER = (By.ID, "SiteTitle")

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    """For checking if the Page Header text matches"""
    def get_header_value(self):
        if self.is_visible(self.HEADER):
            return self.get_element_text(self.HEADER)
```

> And below is the corresponding test class for Home Page (test_HomePage.py):

```html
import pytest
from Config.config import TestData
from Tests.test_Base import BaseTest
from Pages.LoginPage import LoginPage

class Test_Home(BaseTest):

    def test_check_home_page_header(self):
        self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        homepage = self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)
        home_header = homepage.get_header_value()
        assert home_header == TestData.HOME_PAGE_HEADER
```

I'm really stuck since long on this, since I have implemented similar code pattern for my other test project and it was working as expected. Please let me know if any more details are required. TIA.

Comment: Is header visible?

Comment: @vitaliis - yes it is. Its a text which I'm trying to match and assert.

Comment: Are you successfully logged in or not?

Comment: It looks like either login or password fields locators are not correct and you are not logged in. I would be more sure if I saw the code and site.

Comment: @vitaliis - yes my code is able to call the URL, enter the username and password (test_LoginPage.py - this file was created to test login functionality) and reach the Home page. It is here where the tests are failing. The test (test_check_home_page_header) is failing with the above TimeOutException.

Edit : Login Page file updated, for your review, since this is an internal website won't be able to share a public URL.

Comment: Can you print `home_header` and print `TestData.HOME_PAGE_HEADER`?

Comment: Also, maybe timeout in `def is_visible` is not enough for logging in (opening next page after you are logged in)?

Comment: Revise `get_header_value` method. Try running tests without `is_visible` inside this method and replace it with time.sleep(10) temporarily for debugging.

Comment: Add `get_element_text` definition to your question. It may also be a problem

Comment: @vitaliis - thanks for all the help, really appreciated. I have updated the files per your request in the question. Now for clarification, below is the flow:

>BasePage.py (contains all the locator definition)
>LoginPage.py (contains all the Login Page actions)
>test_LoginPage.py (pytest code to validate the actions defined in LoginPage.py)
>HomePage.py (contains all the Home Page actions)
>test_HomePage.py (pytest code to validate the actions defined in HomePage.py). This file extends the LoginPage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232749/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-dashakt).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think that the problem is this function:

```
class Test_Home(BaseTest):
    def test_check_home_page_header(self):
        self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        homepage = self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)  # Doing login after logged in?
        home_header = homepage.get_header_value()
        assert home_header == TestData.HOME_PAGE_HEADER
```

You are trying to enter login and password on a home page, not on login page. You logged in previously here:

```
import pytest
from Config.config import TestData
from Tests.test_Base import BaseTest
from Pages.LoginPage import LoginPagecode

class Test_Login(BaseTest):
    
  def test_login_page_title(self):
      self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
      title = self.loginPage.get_title(TestData.LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE)
      assert title == TestData.LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE

  def test_login(self):
      self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
      self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)
```

Why I think so?
Because of this information from stacktrace:

```
\Pages\LoginPage.py:29: in do_login
    self.do_send_keys(self.UNAME, username)
..\Pages\BasePage.py:19: in do_send_keys
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text)
```

You are trying to input a username, but the field is not found.

So, try the following:

1. Delete `homepage = self.loginPage.do_login(TestData.U_NAME, TestData.P_WD)` from `test_check_home_page_header` and rerun the test
2. Clear cookies if you are logging in before each test.